# Rails: Customizing Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, json-api

Let's say I have a `ProductsController` with this `index` method:

```
def index
 @products = Product.all
end
```

Rails will, by default, render a view file (views/products/index.json.jbuilder).

What if I want to render it this way:

```
render jsonapi: @data
```

For every method, I need to specify `render jsonapi: @data`, like this:

```
def index
 @data = Product.all
 render jsonapi: @data
end
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating this?

I would like to create a file, like `jsonapi_rendering.rb` with `render jsonapi: @data`
and the controller would automatically use this file to render.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628487/how-to-render-json-for-all-actions-from-the-after-action-filter-in-applicationco

Comment: The implicit rendering of views is handled by  ActionController::ImplicitRender#default_render. While you could overide it its really part of the Rails internals and there are better ways of doing this explicitly like for the Responders gem. With responders you just write `respond_with Product.all`.

Comment: @Clara that answer is badly out of date though - the `respond_with` method was removed from Rails eons ago and now lives in the responders gem.

Comment: To expand on implicit vs explicit - Implicit rendering works since the heuristics are quite simple. It either finds a correct view, sends a 204 No Content (for API controllers) or raises an exception. If you want to override that and render meaningful JSON (or no JSON) responses you're going to need far more complexity and you're going to be shoehorning all that into single method with way to much magic involved. Use inheritance, the responders gem and composition instead to DRY your code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new class that inherits from the ApplicationController and using the [default_render](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/BasicImplicitRender/default_render) method:

```
def default_render
  render jsonapi: @data
end
```